# Showing that integral w.r.t. counting measure is the summation using a particular definition of integral.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, S, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $A_1,A_2,...,A_k$ be an S- partition P of X: this means that $A_i$'s are elements of the sigma algebra $S$ and that $\bigcup_{1\le i\le k} A_i=X$.

Let $f:X\to [0,\infty]$ be S-measurable. Lower Lebesgue sum is defined as $L(f, P)=\sum_{j=1}^k \inf_{x\in A_j} f(x)\mu (A_j)$. Then, $\int f , d\mu := \sup \{L(f,P): P$ is an $S-$ partition of $X$}.

With this definition of integral, how can I show that the counting measure on $Z^+$ is the summation?
(i.e., **if $(b_n)$ is a sequence of non negative integers and $b: Z^+\to [0,\infty]: n\mapsto b_n$, then $\int b \,dc=\sum_n b_n$,** where c is the counting measure.)

It is not known yet that $\int (f+g) d\mu= \int f +\int g$.

Let $A_i$'s $(1\le i\le k)$ be a partition of $Z^+$, which will be denoted by $P$. Let's denote $\inf_{x\in A_i} b(x)= b^{(i)}$.

$L(X, P)=\sum_{1\le i\le k} b^{(i)} c(A_i)$.

The problem here is that if all $b_i$'s were given to positive, then necessarily one of $A_i$'s must be an infinite set hence $c(A_i)$ for that $i$ is $\infty$. So $L(X,P)=\infty\implies \sup L(X,P)=\int b \,dc=\infty= \sum b_i$. But this is not true for example when $b_n= \frac 1{n^2}$.

So I don't understand how to prove the highlighted statement. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$I'm going to choose notation that's a bit more pleasant for me. Let's consider the measure space $(\Bbb N,\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N),\nu)$ where $\nu$ is the counting measure.

Take a summable sequence of nonnegative numbers $(\alpha_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$. This can be viewed as a nonnegative measurable function $\alpha:\Bbb N\to[0,\infty)$. The case where $\sum_{n\ge1}\alpha_n=\infty$ is similarly handled.

Write $S^+(\alpha)$ for the space of nonnegative simple functions that are bounded by $\alpha$. Note if $\varphi\in S^+(\alpha)$, then there are finitely many $k_1,\cdots,k_m\in\Bbb N$ with: $$\sum_{j=1}^m\varphi(k_j):=\int_{\Bbb N}\varphi\d\nu\le\int_{\Bbb N}\alpha\d\nu$$Where the inequality is by definition and $\varphi(k_j)\le\alpha_{k_j}$ for all $1\le j\le m$. Because the values of $\varphi(\bullet)$ may be chosen as any nonnegative reals $\le\alpha_\bullet$, it's clear for any selection of distinct $k_1,\cdots,k_m\in\Bbb N$, we have - by choosing $\varphi$ suitably, namely $\varphi(k_j):=\alpha_{k_j}$ and $\varphi(n)=0$ otherwise - the inequality: $$\tag{$\ast$}\sum_{j=1}^m\alpha_{k_j}\le\int_{\Bbb N}\alpha\d\nu$$

---

Feel free to continue. The rest is below. You want to show that $\sum_{n\ge1}\alpha_n$ is both larger than the integrals of all simples but that it can come arbitrarily close to the integral of a simple ~ a finite partial sum.

N.B. it was important that we could define $\varphi$ with great freedom, since all functions out of this measure space are trivially measurable.

---

> We can also get: $$\tag{$\ast\ast$}\int_{\Bbb N}\varphi\d\nu=\sum_{j=1}^m\varphi(k_j)\le\sum_{j=1}^m\alpha_{k_j}\le\sum_{n\ge1}\alpha_n$$

> By choosing $m$ as large as we wish and $k_1,\cdots,k_m$ howsoever we wish, for example we could choose $k_1=1,k_2=2,\cdots,k_m=m$ and let $m\to\infty$ in $(\ast)$, we would get: $$\sum_{n\ge1}\alpha_n\le\int_{\Bbb N}\alpha\d\nu$$

> After taking suprema in $(\ast\ast)$, we find: $$\sum_{n\ge1}\alpha_n\le\int_{\Bbb N}\alpha\d\nu\le\sum_{n\ge1}\alpha_n\quad\therefore\quad\sum_{n\ge1}\alpha_n=\int_{\Bbb N}\alpha\d\nu$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have also posted an answer below which uses the definition only.

Comment: @Koro Oh I see- you’re using a slightly different definition. My post uses only ‘the’ definition via simple functions which is the only definition I’ve ever seen

Answer (score 0):

For any $k\in \mathbb N$, $\{1\}, \{2\},..., \{k\}$, $Z^+- \{1,2,...,k\}$ is a partition $P$ of $Z^+$. So we have  $L(b, P)=\sum_{i=1}^k b_i$. It follows that $\int f dc\ge \sum_{i=1}^k b_i$ for all $k$. Letting $k\to \infty$, we get $\int f dc\ge \sum_i b_i$.

For the reverse inequality,  let $P=\{A_1,...,A_k\}$ be any partition of $Z^+$. We have $L(b, P)= \sum_{i=1}^k (\inf_{A_i} b) c(A_i)\le \sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i$, where the last inequality is by non negativity of $b_i$'s. It follows that $\int f\, dc\le \sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i.$

By the two inequalities, we are done.