# Limit of sequences and functions with extended real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, analysis

I'm trying to understand limit of sequences and functions from a topological standpoint. I have searched this site and some textbooks but unfortunately failed to find a unified and comprehensive answer.

I now understand the [order topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Order_and_topological_properties) on extended real numbers $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$, and the definition of [limit of functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Functions_on_topological_spaces) in a topological space. I want to know what these two equations mean:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=q 
\end{equation}
where $\{a_n\}$ is a real-valued sequence and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Here are my questions:

1. For the second equation (limit of a function), I have seen things like $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=-\infty$. Is the writer using order topology on $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ by default (for both the codomain and domain)? Are all limits of $f$, with or without infinity involved, from what I have learned since elementary calculus classes, compatible with the order topology on $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$? I think the answer for this question is "yes and yes", but I hope to get a confirmation.
2. Still the second equation (limit of a function). I know that if we only consider $\mathbb{R}$, the regular [metric topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_line#As_a_metric_space) is the same as order topology. But for $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$, is there a metric topology that's the same as order topology? If not, is there a metric topology that can reasonably define limits including $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=-\infty$ (which has the same meaning as the limit defined by order topology)?
3. For the first equation (limit of a sequence), what does it mean (especially when $b=\infty$)? Can it be defined using the limit of functions? Is it viewing $\{a_n\}$ as a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$? What topology is used?
4. In addition to limit of a sequence, is the summation sign $\sum_1^\infty c_n$ still defined by the limit of the partial sum sequence $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_1^N c_n$? Can it somehow be defined as the sum over the set $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: The link provided in your question leads to a Wikipedia page that confirms that the order Topology on the extended reals is metrizable, in fact, the extended reals are homeomorphic to a closed interval in the reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(1)$, "yes and yes" is correct. Note that we don't *need* to introduce $\overline{\Bbb R}$ though, since it's easy enough to make independent definitions of $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}$ and what it means for $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\text{something}$.

$(2)$, yes, $\overline{\Bbb R}\cong[-1,1]$ via, e.g., $x\mapsto\tanh x$ will show that $\overline{\Bbb R}$ is metrisable. There are maaaaaany many choices of (order preserving) homeomorphism here.

For $(3)$, formally sequences are *defined* to be functions $\alpha:\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$. If you really want to understand the limits topologically, you can consider $\Bbb N$ as a subspace of $\Bbb N^\ast$ its Alexandroff compactification and $\Bbb R$ as a subspace of $\overline{\Bbb R}$; then, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha_n$ is precisely the topological limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha$ considering $\alpha:\Bbb N^\ast\to\overline{\Bbb R}$. This works for the cases $|b|=\infty$ too.

For $(4)$, I'm not sure how this relates to the rest of your question but: it is context-dependent what $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n$ means. Often it will mean $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Nc_n$. Sometimes it will mean the Lebesgue-sum $\int_{\Bbb N}c\,\mathrm{d}\nu$ where $\nu$ is the counting measure. This is maybe a "sum over the set $\Bbb N$" as you wanted. If the latter is defined, then it agrees with the former, but the former makes sense in a more general context. More on that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4688800) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4703868).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For (3), it might take a while for me to learn about the Alexandroff compactification. Can we just use the subspace topology on $\mathbb{N}\cup \infty$ (topology inherited from the order topology on extended reals)? It seems to me that the limit at infinity makes sense in this topology.

Comment: @DanielMendoza A simple way to restate the Alexandroff compactification of $\Bbb N$ (or for any discrete space, for that matter) is $\Bbb N\cup\{\omega\}$ where $\{\omega\}$ is some point not in $\Bbb N$ we adjoin the following sets to the topology: $\{\omega\}\cup K$ where $K\subseteq\Bbb N$ is infinite. That does indeed agree with the subspace topology on $\Bbb N\cup\{\infty\}\subseteq\overline{\Bbb R}$